# Meaning of "Nothing is working here like the rest of the world?"

Tags: meaning, grammar

I would like to know whether this phase has negative impact or it can be positive.

Comment: In what context did you hear this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not an English expression but merely a sentence where a small place is compared to a bigger place.

I believe it implies a negative meaning, and I am not sure if it would have any impact at all unless you think it would.

It would be great if you could provide a proper context, in which you intend to use this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think, "it's not an English expression" is what I really want to know. In my mother tongue it is a sort of positive phrase and I used it in a email which brought lost of misunderstanding.

Comment: @40tike- Literal translation from one lang to another could cause a lot of misunderstandings, and are better to avoid. If you are a new learner, then try to stick with the simple usage of English grammar and vocabulary for some time.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written it – on its own, absent of any context – it is very ambiguous.

I can think of at least two possible meanings:

Let's say a computer virus is wreaking havoc on the computers that control the financial markets.  A troubleshooter in Amsterdam is on the phone with someone in Bombay, who says, “*Nothing is working here like the rest of the world*,” meaning, “*Our computers are down, just like everyone else's*.”

Or maybe someone is visiting a state-of-the-art manufacturing plant, marveling at the efficiency of the operations.  The plant manager proudly proclaims, “*Nothing is working here like the rest of the world*,” meaning, “This plant is very modern; it incorporates some advanced technologies and innovative practices that no one else is using.”

It's worth noting that neither of these uses is particularly positive or negative; in both cases, the speaking is merely stating factual information.